# What has changed that broke this Solr Query?

Tags: solr, typo3, facet

we used this solr query as a general filter

```
-(eventStart_tDateS:* OR -eventStart_tDateS:[NOW/DAY TO *]) OR -(eventEnd_tDateS:* OR -eventEnd_tDateS:[NOW/DAY TO *])
```

to achive the following:

1. get only events which take place in the future

and

2. get also all facets without that field

so we filtered our events for only future events and filtered all other types other then events but without any effect.

it worked until we updated to solr 7.6, can anybody figure out was has changed that could break this query?

_tDateS is deprecated but is still in solr 7.6 for backwards compatibility

Comment: Start by decompositing your query - find out which parts doesn't work any longer. In general though, you want to start with `*:*` as the collection of documents to filter, then add the negative queries that remove them.

Comment: ye the solution kinda works like that, i will post the result tomorrow at work, thanks @MatsLindh

Comment: well... After vacation so to speak sry for delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how the query looks like after the rework, still not sure why the old version broke after the update

```
-(eventStart_tDateS:[* TO *] OR -eventStart_tDateS:[NOW/DAY TO *]) OR -(eventEnd_tDateS:[* TO *] OR -eventEnd_tDateS:[NOW/DAY TO *])
```

Comment: @MatsLindh may i ask you for a comment on the comparison of the two queries?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are working on an empty core.